# Migrations not reflecting after making Migrations in Django in Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, migration

I creating Django app and connect it with Docker along postgres db. While start with docker server is running fine but I did migrations by going into container of Django app but those migrations are not reflecting into DB(tables not created as per the model).

```
# ======Docker compose.yml file===

version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=eshop
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    container_name: admin_db
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 54321:5432

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python eshop/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvONC.jpg)

I want to know how to do migrations while django and postgres are runing using docker such that after migrations tables will be created in postgres